# Can the HTML5 geolocation accuracy be detected?

Tags: html, geolocation

When using the HTML5 `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` on a website, the result contains the coordinates of the website visitor (if the browser does support this feature).

However, the *accuracy* highly depends on the visitors device (i.e. mobile with GPS, WLAN; stationary with a specific browser; etc).

---

**Is it possible to find out about the *accuracy* of the returned coordinates, i.e. if they are a rough estimate or highly precise?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface):

```
interface Coordinates {
  ...
  readonly attribute double accuracy;
  readonly attribute double? altitudeAccuracy;
  ...
};
```

> The `accuracy` attribute denotes the accuracy level of the latitude and longitude coordinates. It is specified in meters and must be supported by all implementations.
>
> The `altitudeAccuracy` attribute is specified in meters. If the implementation cannot provide altitude information, the value of this attribute must be `null`.
>
> The `accuracy` and `altitudeAccuracy` values returned by an implementation should correspond to a 95% confidence level.

If you want highly precise result, then set [`enableHighAccuracy`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_options_interface) option to `true`.

Comment: Thank you very  much, the confidence level was probably what I really was asking for.